# If $x^y y^x z^z=c$, then find $\frac {\partial^2z}{\partial x \,\partial y}$ at $x=y=z$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $x^y y^x z^z=c$, then find $\dfrac {\partial^2z}{\partial x \,\partial y}$ at $x=y=z$.

I tried taking $\log$ but that doesn't help.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

This is what I have tried:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Taking log should help you. I worked and I got a result of $-\frac{3}{z(1+logz)}$.  Is it a homework problem and would you if it is correct. (should be!!)

Comment: @satishramanathan, I have added my work. Can you please tell me how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Hopefully the image is clear and helpful
[image]

Comment: how do you get $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-1$ ?

Comment: On the condition that it is x=y=z

Comment: I think we will use this condition in the very end.

Comment: May be you are right.  If it is so you get the general prinicple

Comment: How your RHS turns out to be $0$?

Comment: differentiation of a constant is 0

Comment: How can you call them LHS and RHS?
On one hand your are differentiating $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ with respect to x, on the other hand you have differentiation of  $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} (1+ log \ z)$

Comment: Absolutely good catch!! my dear fellow.  Change the solution in such a manner that you differentiate $-logx-\frac{x}{y}$ and then divide by (1+logz) that will be your answer

Comment: I have given the edited answer, please take a look and confirm if you got it correct

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^y y^x z^z=c$ gives 
$$F=y\ln x+x\ln y+z\ln z=0$$
with $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z_y=-\dfrac{F_y}{F_z}$ and then
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{x+y}{xy(1+\ln z)}$$

Comment: I got $\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}= \frac {-(x+y\  ln x)}{y(1+ln \ z)}$, now while differentiating with respect to $x$, are we using quotient rule?

Comment: Correct. yes using quotient rule.

Comment: I have added my attempt. But I can't see it coming from there. Can you please help me further?

Comment: I think you are just differentiating the numerator, and then multiplying by $x$.